# Зачем распознавать отдельные фонемы?

Tags: нейронные-сети, распознавание, распознавание-речи, text-to-speech

Изучая распознавание речи, наткнулся на [данную статью](http://m.habr.com/company/yandex/blog/198556/). В ней происходит распознавание *фонем*, а затем их объединение в слова.

Зачем так делать, ведь можно разбить входящий поток на слова, затем сгенерировать *MFCC* для них и сравнивать уже *MFCC* со словарем через нейронную сеть? Или так нельзя?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что в аудиопотоке нет такого понятия как слово/слова. Есть поток аудиоряда и выделить в нем слова без использования тех же нейронных сетей очень сложно - разные люди обладают разным произношением, мелодикой, скоростью произношения и т.д. Иногда целая фраза/предложение звучит слитно (без пауз), в других случаях люди делают паузы при произношении единственного слова.

В общем если бы было легко разбить аудиопоток на слова, то задача распознавания речи сильно упростилась бы...

Comment: Но тогда каким образом определяется промежуток между словами при объединении фонем в слова?

Comment: Если хотите понять как это работает, то могу посоветовать понять как работает [LSTM](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C). Насколько мне известно наиболее удачные модели распознавания речи используют [LSTM](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C).